# Is it possible to sort by two columns?

Tags: org-mode

I'm using windows 10 and emacs 26.1.

In org mode if I want to sort by one column I use

```
org-sort
```

It's sort by `text, time, function`.

Nice.

But what about sorting by two or more columns?

Comment: `org-table-sort-lines` generates sort keys from a single given column, so no support for multiple column sorting. You'll need to ad a new column that combines other columns into a valid key for sorting.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In a [similar, 1 year old, question on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/5zgknu/how_do_i_multicolumn_sort_an_orgmode_table/) a solution is presented:

You need to sort columns individually in the opposite order of priority.

Example:
You have following table:

```
| C1 | C2 | C3     |
|----+----+--------|
| c  |  1 | true 6 |
| b  |  2 | true 5 |
| a  |  3 | true 3 |
| a  |  2 | true 2 |
| b  |  1 | true 4 |
| a  |  1 | true 1 |
```

---

If you want this result:

```
| C1 | C2 | C3     |
|----+----+--------|
| a  |  1 | true 1 |
| a  |  2 | true 2 |
| a  |  3 | true 3 |
| b  |  1 | true 4 |
| b  |  2 | true 5 |
| c  |  1 | true 6 |
```

You have to sort the table in following order:

1. Column: C2 ; sort order n (numeric)
2. Column: C1 ; sort order a (alphabetic)

---

If you want instead this result:

```
| C1 | C2 | C3     |
|----+----+--------|
| a  |  1 | true 1 |
| b  |  1 | true 4 |
| c  |  1 | true 6 |
| a  |  2 | true 2 |
| b  |  2 | true 5 |
| a  |  3 | true 3 |
```

You need to do this sort order:

1. Column C1 ; sort order a (alphabetic)
2. Column C2 ; sort order n (numeric)

Comment: "For example, to sort by column A, then by column B for equal As, then by column C for equal As and Bs, just sort the table by column C, then by column B, then by column A." - what does it mean B for equal As  ?

Comment: @Alexei see example in my answer